Pipedrive Custom Form - Activating Marketing Status
I have a WordPress site with a custom PHP form connected to Pipedrive using the Pipedrive API. I added a checkbox to this form to serve as consent for email marketing (i.e., newsletter subscription). Is it possible to set the marketing status in Pipedrive to "Subscribed" when this checkbox is selected?
I have tried adding a custom field, but it doesn’t seem to connect with Pipedrive’s built-in Marketing Status. I wanted to set the marketing status of the person who submitted our form to "Subscribed" within Pipedrive when the checkbox is selected?
